# Finding functional values

Tags: functions

I am dealing with a certain function f satisfying
 f(3x) = 3f(x)
for any positive real number x.
Also f(x) = 1 - |x-2| for all real x in the interval [1,3].
Now I am trying to formulate a general expression to obtain the functional value at integers. 
Consider f(2001) which can be written as : 
f(2001) = 3*f(2001) = 9*f(667).
But 667 is not divisible by 3. Neither could I establish any periodicity. How can I find such a functional value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually it is easy to find out what you are trying to do!!
of course you can find a general formula for the function f at all integers but i am just showing the case for f(2001). just follow the algorithm, and that is the way you can get the value at all integers.
f(2001)=3*f(667)=9*f(667/3)=27*f(667/9)=81*f(667/27)=243*f(667/81)=729*f(667/243). actually you go on extracting powers of three from the number f(n) and writing it as (3^k)*f(n/3^(k-1)) till the integer n/3^(k-1) comes within the interval [1,3] for which you know the functional value at n/3^(k-1).
In this particular case,
f(2001)=729*f(667/243)=729*(1-|667/243-2|)=186.
in fact you can prove that you will always get an integer as a functional value of an integer.
However i have not checked what to do in case of the negative integers.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: since $3^6<2001<3^7$ we have $1<2001/3^6<3$, so that
$$
f(2001)=3^6 f\left({2001\over 3^6}\right)=3^6\left(1-\left|{2001\over 3^6}-2\right|\right).
$$

Answer (score 0):

You may wish to look at the [floor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions) and log functions to find what power of 3 to divide by. The pertinent inequality is that $m\leq f(x) < m+1 \implies m = \lfloor f(x) \rfloor$.

For $3^6 < 2001 < 3^7$, we have $6 \leq \log_3 2001 < 7$, then $6 = \lfloor \log_3 2001 \rfloor$.